# How to generate a table in R that extracts the description from the help page for each of the functions defined in a package?

Tags: r

I'm trying to learn Text Mining and I was asked to generate a table which is containing the descriptions of the functions defined in an R package.

I know how to extract the helpfile and look at the descriptions (`tm` is the package I'm using):

`library(help=tm)`

But I could not extract them in a tabular format.

How do I do this? Can anybody help me, please?

Thanks.

Comment: See the source for `help.start` which should give the file path to the HTML versions of the help files. You could then read the HTML files with `rvest`.